# Git - hide merge commits from upstream

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I'm using the following workflow for project on Github.

1. Fork the repository
2. Merge base `master` to forked `master`
3. Create a branch from forked `master` and implement something
4. Create a pull request from my branch to base `master`
5. After checks and review, maintainer merges my branch to base `master`.
6. Goto 2.

The problem is 2. At first I wasn't expierenced with git, so I did this via the pull request in my fork. Now I do `git pull upstream && git merge upstream/master`, which creates a new merge commit. After some such merges, my PRs looks like this:
[image: Bunch of merge commits]

As you see, there is a bunch of merge commits. It's really ugly, and it may be quite hard to understand what exactly I want to merge. Moreover, this list grows every time I merge base `master` to my fork.

Is there a way to hide/remove them? At this moment, I can only consider deleting and re-creating fork every time PR is done, but that's not good, because I may work on A, then switch to B, merge B, go back to A etc. 
`git rebase` actually doesn't hide them: merged commits are listed in PR with `$user authored and $me commited`.

Comment: Assuming the maintainer does an actual merge and not a squash/rebase merge, you should be syncing your fork’s branch by “fast-forwarding”. As far as I know, there’s no easy way to do that with GitHub, but you can do it locally by fetching from both remotes and doing `git merge maintainers-remote/master` followed by `git push`. (`git merge --ff-only` if you want to produce an error instead of a merge commit when a fast-forward isn’t possible.)

Answer (score 1):

To fix your currently "broken" PR, you can [squash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) all your commits into a single commit. You can do this on the command line with `git rebase -i`, and changing `pick` to `squash` on all but the first commit.

GitHub actually implements this for you as well - if you click the dropdown next to the `Merge pull request` button, there is an option for `Squash & merge`, which does the same thing.